# How to convert this for loop into a vectorized operation

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, vectorization

How might I convert the for loop in the function fin() into a vectorized operation?
I am trying to remove all the words from the .txt file that contain any of the forbidden letters provided, receiving these words as an output.

The input code is provided here: https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkPython2/blob/master/code/words.txt

This code functions correctly, in that it provides the correct output, but does not meet the conditions of using vectorized operations:

```
def avoids(word:str, forbidden_letters:str):
    return set(forbidden_letters.lower()).intersection(set(word.lower().replace(' ', ''))) == set()

def fin(forbidden_letters):
    fin = open('words.txt')
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        if avoids(word, forbidden_letters) == True:
            print(word)

fin('abcde')
```

The head of the expected output being:

```
fifing
fifth
fifthly
fifths
fifty
fig
figging
fight
fighting
fightings
fights
...
```

Because 'abcde' are considered forbidden letters they are not included in the any of the words outputted, hence we expect to see words without these letters.

Comment: please provide the input dataset or a reproducible input. Its impossible to know what you are working with. for more details please read [mre]. its also a good practice to explain (in words) what you are trying to achieve as well as provide your attempt as the situation, since questions of the type "give me code for this" are not that well received on SO. Please read [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for more details. Looking forward to the changes to your question. Thanks! :)

Comment: @AkshaySehgal thank you for your considerate response. I'm fairly new to SO, as well as python as a whole. I've made changes, I hope they are satisfactory to the community's standards.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
# Read in the file and add all lines to a list
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    lines = [this_line.strip().lower() for this_line in f]

# Pandas has a bunch of useful string methods, so we turn the data into a DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=["Lines"])

# This will return all lines in df that don't contain a,b,c,d or e.
df = df[~df.Lines.str.contains("a|b|c|d|e", case=False, regex=True)]

# Optional: If you want to convert back to a list after removing unwanted rows,
# you can do the following:
good_lines = df["Lines"].tolist()
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your input! The use of a|b|c|d|e in your answer inspired an interesting solution I used in which I turned the string of letters into a set, and then joined them with '|' between, to then use that in words.str.contains().

Comment: Glad to hear my answer helped!